# Is there any other way to program a copy operation than to simulate Ctrl+C?

Tags: windows, rust, operating-system, clipboard

I'm working on a translation software that takes words from the screen, and I want to be able to do a copy operation when the user presses the translation shortcut to get the text selected by the user for translation.

I tried to simulate the keyboard pressing Ctrl+C to achieve this, in most cases it works well, but at some point (or in some specific applications) this approach will not work, I guess it is caused by some key conflicts, so I was wondering if the OS provides such an interface to do the copy operation directly?

Comment: It's probably better to let the user do the copying and watch changes in the clipoard rather than you putting the text there. I don't think there is an universial API for having an application fill the windows clipboard.